# Is there a way to add html styled with ids/classes inside of a php variable?

Tags: php, html, css

I am working on creating a form to send a styled email, everything worked fine until I started to add IDs to my html elements inside of my php variable. Is there a reason this does not work? I have tested the html code and it works fine on its own, but when put into a php variable, the page will not run. I looked at a few other posts and they said to just add IDs like I have, but it does not work. Any ideas why?

```
    $email_body = "
      <html>
      <body>
      <style>
          *, *::before, *::after {
              box-sizing: border-box;
              padding:0px;
              margin:0px;
          }
          body {
              width:824px;
              padding:12px;
          }
          .skills {
              display: inline-block;
              width:50%;
              text-align: center;
          }
          .skills > #tr > #td {
              display: inline-block;
          }
          .skills > #tr {
              width:100%;
              font-size: 0px;
          }
          .skills > #tr * {
              font-size: 16px;
          }
          .skills > #tr > #td:nth-child(1) {
              width:28px;
              border:1px lightgray solid;
              padding:2px;
              text-align: left;
          }
          .skills > #tr > #td:nth-child(2) {
              width:320px;
              border:1px lightgray solid;
              padding:2px;
              text-align: left;

          }
          .skills > #tr > #td:nth-child(3) {
              width:36px;
              border:1px lightgray solid;
              padding:2px;
              text-align: left;

          }
          .skills > #tr > #td1 {
              width:16px;
          }
          h3, #centered {
              text-align: center;
          }
          .comments {
              width:784px;
              margin:auto;
          }
          .comments > #trc {
              width:100%;
              font-size: 0px;
          }
          .comments > #trc * {
              font-size:16px;
          }
          .comments > #trc > #tdc {
              display: inline-block;
              border: 1px lightgray solid;
              padding:2px;
          }
          .comments > #trc > #tdc:nth-child(1) {
              width:50px;
          }
          .comments > #trc > #tdc:nth-child(2) {
              width:734px;
          }
          #skillnum {
              padding-left:8px;
              width: 55px;
              text-align: center;
          }
          #info {
              width:150px;
              display:inline-block;
              border: 1px black solid;
              padding:4px;
              font-size: 18px;
          }
          #info2 {
              width:650px;
              display:inline-block;
              border: 1px black solid;
              padding:4px;
              font-size: 18px;
          }
          #sig {
              width:600px;
              text-align:center;
              margin:auto;
          }
          #sig :nth-child(1) {
              width:120px;
              display:inline-block;
              text-align: right;
          }
          #sig :nth-child(2) {
              display:inline-block;
              width:250px;
              border-bottom: 1px solid black;
              text-align: left;
          }
          #sig :nth-child(3) {
              width:50px;
              display:inline-block;
              text-align: right;
          }
          #sig :nth-child(4) {
              border-bottom:1px solid black;
              width:100px;
              display:inline-block;
              text-align: left;
          }
      </style>

      <h3>WEEK 1 - Trainee Evaluation</h3>
      <h3><i>Must be completed at the end of training week.</i></h3>
      <br/>
      <div id="info">Trainee Name</div><div id="info2">$traineeName</div>
      <div id="info">Trainer Name</div><div id="info2">$trainerName</div>
      <div id="info">Date Completed</div><div id="info2">$date</div>
      <br/><br/>
      <h3><i>Fill in the number that represents the student's demonstrated level of knowledge/skill</i></h3>
      <div id="centered">1 = Needs Improvement 2 = Below Average 3 = Meets Expectations 4 = Exceeds Expectations</div><br/>
      <div class="skills">
        <div id="tr">
          <div id="td">1. </div>
          <div id="td">Truck Inspection</div>
          <div id="td">$q1</div>
          <div id="td1"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="tr">
          <div id="td">2. </div>
          <div id="td">Air Brake Test</div>
          <div id="td">$q2</div>
          <div id="td1"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="tr">
          <div id="td">3. </div>
          <div id="td">Seat/Mirror Adjustment</div>
          <div id="td">$q3</div>
          <div id="td1"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="tr">
          <div id="td">4. </div><div id="td">Use of Accelerator</div>
          <div id="td">$q4</div>
          <div id="td1"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="tr">
          <div id="td">5. </div><div id="td">User of Signals and Horn</div>
          <div id="td">$q5</div>
          <div id="td1"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="tr">
          <div id="td">6. </div><div id="td">Use of Brakes/Anticipated Stops</div>
          <div id="td">$q6</div>
          <div id="td1"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="tr">
          <div id="td">7. </div><div id="td">Following Distance</div>
          <div id="td">$q7</div>
          <div id="td1"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="tr">
          <div id="td">8. </div><div id="td">Straight Forward Driving</div>
          <div id="td">$q8</div>
          <div id="td1"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="tr">
          <div id="td">9. </div><div id="td">Straight Backing</div>
          <div id="td">$q9</div>
          <div id="td1"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="tr">
          <div id="td">10. </div><div id="td">Right Turns</div>
          <div id="td">$q10</div>
          <div id="td1"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="tr">
          <div id="td">11. </div><div id="td">Left Turns</div>
          <div id="td">$q11</div>
          <div id="td1"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="tr">
          <div id="td">12. </div><div id="td">Crossing Intersections</div>
          <div id="td">$q12</div>
          <div id="td1"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="tr">
          <div id="td">13. </div><div id="td">Crossing Railroad Tracks</div>
          <div id="td">$q13</div>
          <div id="td1"></div>
        </div>
      </div><div class="skills">
        <div id="tr">
          <div id="td">14. </div><div id="td">Narrow Bridges/Tunnels/Low Underpass</div>
          <div id="td">$q14</div>
        </div>
        <div id="tr">
          <div id="td">15. </div><div id="td">Entering Traffic/Merging</div>
          <div id="td">$q15</div>
        </div>
        <div id="tr">
          <div id="td">16. </div><div id="td">Passing</div>
          <div id="td">$q16</div>
        </div>
        <div id="tr">
          <div id="td">17. </div><div id="td">Lane Changing</div>
          <div id="td">$q17</div>
        </div>
        <div id="tr">
          <div id="td">18. </div><div id="td">Pedestrian/Bicyclist/Motorcylcist Awareness</div>
          <div id="td">$q18</div>
        </div>
        <div id="tr">
          <div id="td">19. </div><div id="td">Adverse/Inclement Weather</div>
          <div id="td">$q19</div>
        </div>
        <div id="tr">
          <div id="td">20. </div><div id="td">Decreased Visibility</div>
          <div id="td">$q20</div>
        </div>
        <div id="tr">
          <div id="td">21. </div><div id="td">DOT Logs</div>
          <div id="td">$q21</div>
        </div>
        <div id="tr">
          <div id="td">22. </div><div id="td">Load Securement Box/Flatbed</div>
          <div id="td">$q22</div>
        </div>
        <div id="tr">
          <div id="td">23. </div><div id="td">Shifting</div>
          <div id="td">$q23</div>
        </div>
        <div id="tr">
          <div id="td">24. </div><div id="td">Sliding Tandems</div>
          <div id="td">$q24</div>
        </div>
        <div id="tr">
          <div id="td">25. </div><div id="td">Coupling/Uncoupling</div>
          <div id="td">$q25</div>
        </div>
        <div id="tr">
          <div id="td">26. </div><div id="td">Following Directions</div>
          <div id="td">$q26</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br/><br/>
      <h3>Comments and Suggestions for Improving Performance</h3>
      <div id="skillnum">Skill #</div>
      <div class="comments">
        <div id="trc">
          <div id="tdc">$s1</div>
          <div id="tdc">$c1</div>
        </div>
        <div id="trc">
          <div id="tdc">$s2</div>
          <div id="tdc">$c2</div>
        </div>
        <div id="trc">
          <div id="tdc">$s3</div>
          <div id="tdc">$c3</div>
        </div>
        <div id="trc">
          <div id="tdc">$s4</div>
          <div id="tdc">$c4</div>
        </div>
        <div id="trc">
          <div id="tdc">$s5</div>
          <div id="tdc">$c5</div>
        </div>
        <div id="trc">
          <div id="tdc">$s6</div>
          <div id="tdc">$c6</div>
        </div>
        <div id="trc">
          <div id="tdc">$s7</div>
          <div id="tdc">$c7</div>
        </div>
        <div id="trc">
          <div id="tdc">$s8</div>
          <div id="tdc">$c8</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <br/>
      <div id="sig"><div>Trainer Signature &nbsp;</div><div></div><div>Date &nbsp;</div><div></div></div>

  </body>
</html>
    ";
```

Comment: Shouldn't your ids be classes?  And is there a need to add those attributes to all those children?

Comment: Smells like a table.

Comment: Where do your variables come from?  Could you use an array or arrays and loop, rather than writing out a long list of html?  There looks to be repeated blocks there.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson By "doesn't work" I mean the webpage appears blank when I add this code to the php variable. It is hosted on godaddy and uses cpanel. If I open the code editor on cpanel it gives an error "Unexpected T String" next to the ids. It also gives me that same error using inline styling. I started using tables at first but I was having some issues making it look exactly how it was supposed to.

Comment: @Progrock yeah the code isn't perfect right now, I just wanted to get it working at first then go back and clean it up as best I can. Also the variables come from a form, but I may try to convert some parts of this into a loop as that would seem to make the code nicer.

Comment: It doesn't work because of the unescaped quotes inside the string. Escape them or use single quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use apostrophe for HTML attributes. Here an example:

```
$variable = "<div class='class-name another-class'>...</div>";
```

Comment: Wow that fixed it for me... I feel dumb for not trying that haha

Comment: @AndrewVince - In the future, add all error messages you get to the question from the start since it tells us what to look for

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Will do.